# Is it possible to import table queries into sqlyog?

Tags: view, sqlyog

I have a few .sql files containing queries for view tables. It would be helpful if I can just import them all at once into a database in sqlyog.

One of the example :

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `viewrankingpointsbachelor` AS 
SELECT 
    SUM(`vpd`.`marks`)  AS `points`,
    `vpd`.`student_no`  AS `student_no`,
    `vpd`.`type`        AS `education_level`,
    `s`.`name`          AS `name`,
    `s`.`gender`        AS `gender`,
    `s`.`campus_id`     AS `campus_id` 
FROM ((`viewpointsdetails` `vpd` 
    JOIN `student` `s` 
        ON(((`s`.`no_pelajar` = `vka`.`no_pelajar`) 
        AND (SUBSTR(`s`.`program_code`,3,1) = 1)))) 
    JOIN `semester` `sem` 
        ON(((`sem`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`sem`.`id`) FROM `semester` 
            WHERE (`sem`.`type` = 'Bachelor'))) 
            AND (CAST(`vpd`.`date` AS DATE) 
                BETWEEN CAST(`sem`.`start` AS DATE) AND CAST(`sem`.`end` AS DATE))))) 
GROUP BY `vpd`.`student_no`,`vpd`.`type`,`s`.`name`,`s`.`gender`,`s`.`campus_id` 
ORDER BY `points` DESC,`s`.`campus_id`$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It is possible to import other than sql dump file? Thanks.

Comment: This is NOT Sql server.

Comment: @RachelAmbler It was the only suggested tag, totally overlooked that since I'm not familiar yet to this site's features... Thanks for the correction.